# Getting data only if the key is available in the dictionary

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, key

I have a Dictionary of following type:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "year_option": {
      "2015": "2015",
      "2016": "2016"
    },
    "month_option": {
      "10": "Oct",
      "11": "Nov",
      "12": "Dec",
      "01": "Jan",
      "02": "Feb",
      "03": "Mar",
      "04": "Apr",
      "05": "May",
      "06": "Jun",
      "07": "Jul",
      "08": "Aug",
      "09": "Sept"
    }
  }
}
```

It's a response from `API`. The keys in the `Dictionary` can vary with each user. So is there any way to get the `Dictionary` values only if the *`key is available`*?

Comment: You should take a look at SwiftyJSON

Comment: @HaneTV No need to use a huge library for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there is a way. Use `if let` to check if there is a key.
For example:

```
if let key1 = yourDict["key1"] {
   // do something with key1
}
```

To use your example:

```
if let filter = yourDict["filter"] as? [String: Any] {
   if let yearOption = filter["year_option"] as? [String: String] {
      // there is the year_option JSON
   }
   if let monthOption = filter["month_option"] as? [String:String] {
      // there is the month option JSON
   }
}
```